# WebSocket disconnections

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I have a production real-time online game on Android that uses `WebSockets`. There are thousands active players in the game and it's crucial to have stable connection (if an opponent loses connection the game is over).

I implemented own WebSocket client and uses Jetty 9.3.14.v20161028 as a server. All work fine, but some users complain about frequent disconnections. According to games statistics some players play hundreds games without disconnections at all, but other players have about 20% loses because of disconnections. So my suggestion was that some mobile operators don't like long connections and forcible close them. Is it possible? At the same time some players reported that even via wifi the disconnection problem exists.

I googled a lot but can't find any useful info. If you have any suggestion or know any details about the problem let me know, please

Comment: Are you implementing a `keep-alive` mechanism in your WebSocket implementation?

Comment: check your `keep-alive` mechanism because a socket can timeout after a particular time

Comment: @Daniel @Collins about `keep-alive`: do you mean ping/pong mechanism? I don't run any pings from client/server (not sure, but believe jetty doesn't send ping automatically). But I send special "alive" messages from client to server and correspondent responses from server every 15 secs. As I said many players don't have disconnection problems, so I suppose my implementation is fine